# Can't run JavaFX applications in Eclipse. There is the tea cup icon but no window

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, javafx

I'm a student and should install JavaFx on my Mac. Then I should run a test code to verify the installation. So I downloaded JavaFx and imported the .jar files to the Eclipse library of my project. After that I wrote the module-info.java file.

Then when I hit run in Eclipse the program starts and I see the Java tea cup icon in the dock. But the strange thing is, there is no window which would display anything. There are no error codes or anything else either. The Java icon can't be closed with a right-click and "close". You have to click terminate in Eclipse.

```
package testpackage;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Label l = new Label("Sie haben FX erfolgreich installiert!");
        l.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(l, 400,150));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Herzlichen Glückwunsch");
        primaryStage.show();
    }


}
```

I don't see a problem with the code and I don't know what I could have done wrong during the installation.
I have installed OpenJDK 13.0.2 and JavaFX-sdk-14. My Mac is on MacOS 10.15.4

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: There is no problem with the code. Do you get any exception ?

Comment: Open the run configurations dialog, and then the "Arguments" tab. Make sure the "Use the -XstartOnFirstThread argument when running with SWT" is **unchecked**.

Comment: I am sure it's a coffee cup, hence the name; *java*.

Comment: @James_D Thank you. Now I'm feeling stupid because of one little checkmark ;)

Comment: @MaximFrank No, it took me a while to figure that out when I had the same issue a while ago. I don't use SWT (and never have), so I actually have no idea what it means, or why it is checked by default. If you use Maven and use the JavaFX Maven archetype, the issue is automatically resolved, but I have no idea what magic they do.