# JavaFX Stage not visible

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to write the simplest code to start learning how JavaFX works. Here is my code:

`package app;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class mainClass extends Application{

    Stage primaryStage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        primaryStage = stage;
        StackPane layout = new StackPane();

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}`

It should just show an empty window. My compilator gives no errors, but nothing shows up, even if I can see my program running in my dock. How is this possible? I'm sure I'm missing some stupid simple thing, but I cannot figure out what it is.

Comment: instead of show use showAndWait() function. Because show method will make the stage visible and quickly vanishes. but showAndWait() method make the stage visible untill stage was closed.

Comment: I have tried running you program as it is i am able to see the stage appearing. i think it was not with the code you have written.

Comment: You haven't said anything about the environment you're running in, but if it's Eclipse, see if the comment below [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60973442) helps.

Comment: I was using intellij ide

Comment: Yes I'm using Eclipse. The latest version. I already used this library on an older version maybe a year ago (I'm just a hobbyist, so I program for a month and then nothing for a year xD) and everything worked fine. Do you think I should blame Eclipse for this?

Comment: @sarathkumar You can't invoke `showAndWait()` on the primary stage. Besides, the `show()` method does not behave as you describe.

Comment: unrelated: java naming conventions, please