# Simplest program using JFrame doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to learn something about how to put some graphics in my application, but I have some problem. 
I just created a JFrame, set a size, set visibility on true but it simply shows nothing. Here is my code.

```
package app;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class mainClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame jimage = new JFrame();
        jimage.setSize(600, 400);
        jimage.setTitle("Prova JFrame");
        jimage.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jimage.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Help please :/

Comment: Works for me. Can you tell us what OS you are on, which version of Java and how you are compiling and running your program.

Comment: I have checked, it works normally.

Comment: try adding jimage.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));, but as mentioned, your code works fine.

Comment: I'm working on Mac OS X Mojave, Eclipse 2020-03 and JDK 14.0.1

Comment: I posted on this site a week ago about a similar problem using JavaFX. I tried to create a simple window on the screen. I received no errors on the console, but nothing showed up. Now I have the same problem but with a different library. How is it possible?

Comment: Maybe you are running into some EDT (EventDispatchingThread) issues? To be 100% safe you should call your setVisible within the EDT using something like: java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            jimage.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

Comment: wumpz, still nothing.

Comment: Maybe I'm about to say something stupid, but I tried to put System.out.println(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()); after .setVisible() method, and I got false. Shouldn't it return true? I'm not familiar with the EDT, so I'm just making some attempts.

Comment: No solution for this?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by nothing. It should show an empty `JFrame` with a title as you can see [here](https://repl.it/repls/ClearcutHotCareware). Also all the unused imports may suggest that that the posted code is not the whole program. Are you using an IDE ?

Comment: I can see that you use Eclipse and you had similar problem with [javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61308046/javafx-stage-not-visible) so the problem is not related to the code. Make sure you run the right class: right click `mainClass` and select run as > java application.

Comment: By nothing I mean...nothing :) I can see the program is running because of the red squared stop button, but nothing appears. Anyway, I tried to run it as Java Application, as you suggested, but still nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
In my Run Configurations I had to uncheck "-Use the -XStartOnFirstThread when launching with SWT", under the Arguments tab. Hope could help someone!

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes.  This code runs fine on my Windows 10, Java 13 JDK, Java 8 compile level.

The order that you call JFrame methods is crucial.  This is the order that I always use.

Save this code.  This is how you start a Swing GUI.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SimpleJFrame implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SimpleJFrame());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame jimage = new JFrame();
        jimage.setTitle("Prova JFrame");
        jimage.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jimage.setSize(600, 400);
        jimage.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        jimage.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```